# Setting CSS to an img inside div that has class inside div that has ID

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this code:

```css
 .image-info > img {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="special-image1">
    <div class="image-itself"></div>
    <div class="image-info">
        <img scr="" alt="SP1" width="248" height="78">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="special-image2">
    <div class="image-itself"></div>
    <div class="image-info">
        <img scr="" alt="SP2" width="248" height="78">
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to change only the img with alt "SP2". Another problem is that the code has generato. Can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: If you're just trying to access that specific image: `#special-image2 img`.  I'm not entirely sure what the alt text has to do with this because you have an ID for each image.

Comment: yes agree with Wounded, you can easily access by id then img..what is your issue then?

Comment: Alt property is not in my main code and I add this here. I can't use this.

Comment: @Sheede we are not talking about alt property..just access the image as WOUNDED suggest.. see this https://jsfiddle.net/5x7fvthc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add an important and code works.
The last code is this:

```css
 .image-info > img {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:green;
}
#special-image2 > .image-info > img {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="special-image1">
    <div class="image-itself"></div>
    <div class="image-info">
        <img scr=""  width="248" height="78">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="special-image2">
    <div class="image-itself"></div>
    <div class="image-info">
        <img scr="" width="248" height="78" style="background-color:yellow;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Css code:

```
img[alt="SP2"]{
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   background-color:red;
}
```

OR

```
#special-image2 img {
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Dear akash;
Alt property is not in my main code and I add this here I can't use this.

Comment: Which thing you can change ? what is not dynamic ?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a selector like this:

```
#special-image-2 img
```

That will get the `img` inside the `div` with `id` `special-image-2`.

If you don't want or can't use the `id` for whatever reason, you could also use:

```
div.image-itself div.image-info img[alt="SP2"]
```

This will match them by `div` class and the value of the `alt` attribute of the `img`.

I would, however, recommend using a class to identify between different types of image elements for your use, since the alt text does have a valid and important use for context and accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't completely get the question but try this `.image-info > img[alt ="SP2"]`

it selects the `img` element having the `alt` vaue of `SP2`

```css
.image-info > img[alt ="SP2"] {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="special-image1">
    <div class="image-itself"></div>
    <div class="image-info">
        <img scr="" alt="SP1" width="248" height="78">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="special-image2">
    <div class="image-itself"></div>
    <div class="image-info">
        <img scr="" alt="SP2" width="248" height="78">
    </div>
</div>
```